# C++ Using delete on 2D-Vector of a struct with float arrays

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a struct like this:

```
struct foo {

  int a,b,c;

  float d; 

  float *array1;

  float *array;

};
```

And now I use this struct for a 8x8 2D-Vector like this:

```
vector< vector<foo> > bar(8);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    bar[i].resize(8);
```

Within my program, "bar" is now filled with data, for example:

```
bar[1][5].array1 = new float[256];
bar[1][5].array2 = new float[256];
// Et cetera.
```

**How can I free the memory used by bar correctly?**

I tried a for-loop for freeing every float array like this:

```
delete [] bar[i][j].array1;
```

But that will result in a heap exception on runtime.

Comment: If your arrays will always have 256 elements, you should consider declaring them in this way: `float array1[256]; float[256] array2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This easiest way to accomplish this would be to create a constructor and destructor:

```
struct foo {

  int a,b,c;
  float d; 
  float *array1;
  float *array;

  foo()
  {
    array1 = array = 0;
  }

  ~foo()
  {
    delete [] array1;
    delete [] array;
  }

};
```

Even better would be members to track the size of array1 & array so that a copy constructor and/or assignment operator could clone them as needed.

Note: by "easiest" I do not mean "best". :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a destructor to your `struct` to clean up those members.

Alternatively you could do as Eduardo León suggests and allocate them as part of the structure.

```
float array1[256];
```

instead of

```
float *array1;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you ought to use `vector<float>` instead of `float*`, [arrays are evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.1).

Second, the way you are freeing the memory is correct, the mistake must be at some other place.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post an actual code fragment?  If you're deleting just the elements you're allocating, there shouldn't be a problem.

I'd suggest a couple things to help narrow it down:

1. Assign NULL to all your pointers on initialization
2. Use shared_ptr types instead of raw float pointers - these will be automatically cleaned up when no references remain.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use an vector or other stl-container, which fits your need.

If it has to be arrays - better use an destructor in your struct, so you need not to think about manually cleanup:

```
  struct foo
  {
    int a,b,c;
    float d; 
    float *array1;
    float *array2;

     foo ()
        : a(0),
        b(0),
        c(0),
        d(0.0),
        array1(NULL),
        array2(NULL)
     { }

     ~foo ()
     {
        delete [] array1;
        delete [] array2;
     }
  };
```

edit: removed check of NULL on `delete []`

Comment: You don't need to check for null when calling `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this destructor to your struct foo:

```
~foo() {
  delete []array1;
  delete []array2;
}
```

I suggest also to create a constructor for you `foo` that initializes those two pointers to 0:

```
foo()
:a(0),b(0),c(0),
 d(0.0), array1(0), array2(0)
{}
```